# how to prepare regex have two conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you please tell me what will be the pattern when three same character not allowed 
I have a name field in which have few validations

1. Name should not contain **test** "text"

I checked using `indexOf` .

1. Name should not contain three consecutive charecters example "abc" , "pqr" ,"xyz"
2. 1. Name should not contain same character three times example "aaa" , "ccc" ,"zzz"

can we make a regex for it. I googled it not found

I tried like this

```
val ='a'
var phonenoRegex = /^a-zA-Z+$/;
if(val.toLowerCase().indexOf('test') !=-1&& phonenoRegex.test(val)){
alert('false')
}else {
alert('true')
}
```

Comment: did you mean `"pqr"` in your second rule?

Comment: `Name should not contain three consecutive charecters` Then what sort of characters *are* allowed, other than alphabetical characters, if alphabetical characters can't occur three times in a row? Or, what do you mean?

Comment: yes "pqr" is not valid

Comment: @CertainPerformance He means it can't contain 3 consecutive letters that are consecutive in the alphabet, like `abc` or `jkl`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think you didn't understand my question

Comment: @Barmar yes ..that is correct

Comment: `a-zA-Z` needs to be in brackets `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: What about `aBC`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance He's converting to lowercase before doing any of the checks.

Comment: @Barmar He has `phonenoRegex.test(val)` so I'm not sure

Comment: @CertainPerformance `aBc` is also wrong

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes I will convert it on lower case sorry

Comment: @CertainPerformance That regexp has both upper and lower case in it, so it allows both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all of this with alternatives in a regexp.

```
if (/test|[^a-z]|(.)\1\1|abc|bcd|cde|def|...|wxy|xyz/i.test(val)) {
    alert('false');
} else {
    alert('true');
}
```

`(.)\1\1` matches 3 repetitions of the same character; `\1` is a back-reference to the character that the `.` matched. You test for consecutive letters by simply listing all of them as alternatives in the regexp (replace `...` with all the missing ones that I skipped). You don't need `toLowerCase()` since the `i` option makes it case-insensitive.